# How to make an Interactive 3D globe for a website

Tags: java-3d

I know this might be a bit far fetched aswell as being very complex; however, I want to make a 3d globe for my site that can be labelled appropriately according to the location. It can be zoomed in and out, and dragged to spin the surface of the globe. It can be in any programming language, but its probably going to be in java 3D

Comment: This question is far too broad for this site.

Comment: Sorry. I just wanted to know if anybody could suggest me how to do it.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not for general product recommendations.  Try doing a Google search for "webgl virtual globe" and see what you can find.

Comment: yes, i have looked into it

Answer (score 1):

Do you know Nasa WorldWind? I used it once in swing, but you can use it in applets, too. You can visit http://goworldwind.org/demos/ to see if it's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

keineAhnung's answer isn't wrong but unfortunately, the Java plugin (especially the applets and Java Webstart) has a bad reputation now and it has become very difficult to use, both for the developers and the end users.

I would rather advise LibGDX with its GWT/WebGL backend so that Harry Campbell (the original poster) can still use Java as a programming language and the source code is translated to Javascript by GWT so that the end users don't need to install the Java plugin.

In a (far?) future, maybe we'll be able to choose which Javascript engine has to be used to manage a web page so that we can use any language as an intermediary solution and a real JVM under the hood. You can have a look at [Bck2Brwsr](http://wiki.apidesign.org/wiki/Bck2Brwsr) in the meantime.